# When should the word "NOW" be used in a sentence.......?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence, word-order

Consider the following 2 sentences:-

- "Now the application is working fine".
- "The application is working fine now".

Which one is grammatically correct and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. Adverbials, like "now" can assume a variety of syntactic positions, e.g. "now the application works fine" " the application now works fine." " the application works fine now"